# Safe to fastboot boot twrp?

Tags: twrp, fastboot

Is it completely safe to `fastboot boot twrp.img` on a version of TWRP that I do not know if it will work?
I will `fastboot flash recovery twrp.img` after verifying it works, or abort the flashing if it doesn't.

I have a [Samsung `SM-P205` with firmware `P205DXS5ATL1`](https://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_tab_a_8_0_&_s_pen_(2019)-9651.php), which I am not certain that it is supported by TWRP ([supported Samsung devices](https://twrp.me/Devices/Samsung/)).

Comment: Usually just booting should not cause problems even if it is not impossible to damage something by booting a non-matching recovery ROM.